# Monotone convergence theorem implies Nested Interval property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Assuming MCT holds we need to prove the NIP

**Monotone Convergence theorem:** A monotone and bounded sequence is convergent.

**Nested Interval Property:** If for all $n\in \mathbb{N}, I_n=[a_n, b_n]$ and $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$ then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n\neq \emptyset $

*Proof:* $(a_n)$ is a monotone a bounded sequence and increasing then it converges to some $a$. We say that $I_n=[a_n, a]$, then $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$, as $a_n<a_{n+1}$. Now the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^k I_n=[a_k,a]$, now we can take  the limit $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^k I_n=a\neq\emptyset$$This proves the NIP.

Does this proof look ok?

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is not O.K. You wrote $I_n=[a_n, a]$. But we have $I_n=[a_n, b_n]$ !

We have:

$a_1 \le .... \le  a_n \le a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1} \le b_b  \le .... \le b_1$. Hence the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded and monotonic, hence  convergent.

Let $a= \lim a_n$ and $b= \lim b_n$. Then we have $a \le b$. Now show that $[a,b ] \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n.$

Comment: why we can't make $a=b_n\forall n$ does it matter how we chose $I_n$, if it satisfies $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$. we just have to show that intersection is non empty right?

Comment: The intervalls $I_n=[a_n, b_n]$ are given ! You cannot change them !

Comment: why are they given? Haven't you constructed them but ordering them. I assumed that we are given only one sequence that is $(a_n)$ and it is monotone. Do you mean that it is given that $a_n, b_n$ are monotone. I started using MCT and assumed a single convergent sequence, what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong.

A missing detail:

The OP wants to prove MCT $\rightarrow$ NIP.

As User Fred points out for all $I_n =[a_n,b_n]$ with $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \not = \emptyset.$

Recall:

$a_1\le a_2\le...\le a_n \le a \le $

$b \le b_n\le...\le b_2\le b_1$,

where $a=\lim a_n,$ and $b =\lim b_n.$

For $x \in [a,b]$ , i.e. $a \le x\le b$ we have:

$a_n \le a \le x \le b \le b_n$ for  $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e.

$x \in I_n$ for all $n$, hence

$[a,b] \subset \displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n $.

Note: $[a,b] \not = \emptyset$

(Has at least one element).

Comment: I have a question. You have assumed that an <= a for all n, where a is the limit of (an). But without Axiom of Completeness how can we say that an<=a for all n? an might be greater than or equal to a for some n right? Is it not why we use absolute value when we say an - a < epsilon? Please ignore this if you have assumed axiom of completeness :)

Comment: AK-47. If $a_n$ is increasing,  convergent to $a$, this implies $a_n \le a$ for all $n$. Why? Assume to the contrary there is a $n_0$ with $a <a_{n_0}$, then for $n\ge n_0:$ $a<a_{n_0}< a_n$. Contradiction.(Why?). Is this your  question?

Comment: But isn't that true because we assume the axiom of completeness? What if we do not assume AoC? Because we assume that supremum exists, we can say that if (an) is increasing and bounded then lim an = sup(an). Hence, an <= a for all n. I have tried proving this in the answers below. Please give it a look. Thanks :)

Comment: ak47. Am a  bit confused about what is and  where is exactly your concern. Why not, as an exercise, you point out exactly where and what you are doubting. If you have $a_n \le a$ and $a_n$ increasing your proof is fine. Where exactly does the Axiom come in according to you?

Comment: So, an increasing bounded sequence will converge to its supremum. The existence of supremum is guaranteed by the axiom of completeness. There does not exist any n such that an <= sup(an). So in this case I can say that no an > lim (an). But if we don't use the AoC, we can't claim that the supremum exists. So now (an) converges but we can't directly say that it converges to the supremum, which is why I ask that how to eliminate the case where an > lim(an)? Also thanks a lot for discussing this with me! I apologise for not making clear arguments.

Comment: ak47. MCT uses completeness, i. e. existence of a supremum. The supremum is the limit. All $a_n$ in our case are less or equal to sup. No $a_n >$sup. Look up Monotone Conv. Theorem in Wiki. Well work it out:) No worry:)

Comment: Peter Szilas I get your point that MCT uses completeness in its proof. As I have mentioned in my answer, while reading Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis I came across a problem which explicitly stated that NIP was to be proven with MCT without using AoC. That is what has stumped me. And that's why I haven't used supremum in my answer, but I am not convinced with my proof.

Comment: Let's leave it for a moment. You can ask another question (mathsstack) if and when you can pinpoint your specific problem.